# Which processor/core is this process/service using?

Tags: cpu, threading, threads, multitasking

What can i use to monitor which processor/core/thread an application is using? I have 16 processors and want to know which processor a specific application is using. I am running Windows Server 2003 R2 64-bit.

Process Explorer doesn't tell me this... it lets me set processor affinity but doesn't tell me which core a process is using!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually *set* an affinity, it can use any core available. It can even rapidly switch between using different cores, making any such display unusable.